# How do I create multiple records in one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `Vendor` and `Product` models. A `vendor has_many products`, and a `product belongs_to vendor`.

Once a `vendor` is created, I would like to add multiple `products` in one form.

How do I do that?

I looked at the Railscast for Nested Model Forms, but that's not exactly what I want to do. For starters, he is working within the `_form` partial for the `Survey` model - which I don't necessarily want to do here.

All I want to do is on the `Product#new` view, it allows the user to enter 1 or more than 1 products all at the same time.

Yes, those products will belong to a vendor - but I don't want the user to have to `edit` the vendor to be able to add multiple products.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at cocoon - https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

It would allow you to add and remove sets of nested fields for your products

Comment: Right...that's exactly what I am trying not to do. All I want to do is to be able to add multiple products at once - rather than 1 product at a time.

Comment: I don,'t follow you - you have to enter the information for your different products somewhere! You don't need to show the vendor details on your form if you don't want to.